# install failed due duplicate permission

Tags: android, gradle, android-permissions

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help guys, I made a mistake and I thought I have to have SCREEN_OFF permission in order to receive that intent. After I removed from the manifest, everything was fine.
Thanks anyway!

**ORIGINAL POST:**

So I have the following error message when I am trying to install the release version of the application next to the buildType versions:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
```

Under the buildTypes I am using:

```
           applicationIdSuffix '.envfirst'
```

and on the other type I am using:

```
           applicationIdSuffix '.envsecond'
```

The release buildType doensn't have any applicationIdSuffix, it's using the default one from default config.

The application has a registered broadcastReceiver when the user turning the screen off.

Comment: Why are you defining a custom permission named `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF`?

Comment: Maybe confusion of `<permission .../>` with `<uses-permission ... />`.

Comment: I do believe this is not a custom permission this is android system permission if the user turn the screen of. I have both <permission .../> and <uses-permission .../> declared

Comment: My answer should be un-accepted. The first problem as others have noted is that you are confusing a broadcast intent action with a permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Lollipop, the permission is "owned" by the signature of the app that first declared it.

If your release version is signed differently (as I'm sure it is), it won't be able to declare the same permission. You'll need to uninstall the debug version first.

Comment: I Jeffrey, thanks for getting back to me. I am a bit confused because what about an another permission such as BOOT_COMPLETED ? Based on what you saying only one app / phone can have it? The apps are signed differently

Comment: You are confusing declare and use. `<permission ` means declare. You are adding a new permission. `<uses-permission ..` means you wish to use, or be granted the permission. I think you want to *use* the `SCREEN_OFF` permission. Android declares that. Your app will not be allowed to declare it.

Comment: ok, so what I using there in term of name is correct, but I don't need to declare but use?

Comment: It's fine to listen for `SCREEN_OFF`. You should have a `<uses-permission...` for it in your manifest. But not a `<permission` tag for it.

Comment: thanks Jeffrey, after I removed the <permission> tag from my manifest and I have only <uses-permission> it works!